# Load a JSON file from API with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, api, get

I am hanging with this problem:
I am trying to get the JSON file from http://finance.google.com/finance/info?client=ig&q=NASDAQ:TSLA with this code:

```
$("document").ready(function () {
    // Calling function
    reLoad();

    function reLoad() {
        $.getJSON("http://finance.google.com/finance/info?client=ig&q=NASDAQ:TSLA", function(data) {
            alert(data);
        });

        setTimeout(reLoad, 1000);
    };
});
```

But this isn't working.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You need to define the function **before** you call it, or it won't work.

In this case, that means you need to write `reLoad();` after `function reLoad() { ... }` instead of before.

Comment: @Jaumzera Please do not use backticks (code) for emphasis.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your respond, but when i am testing my code with another json file it works! So my problem is just getting this spezial file from the url "http://finance.google.com/finance/info?client=ig&q=NASDAQ:TSLA", which looks like this:

// [ { "id": "12607212" ,"t" : "TSLA" ,"e" : "NASDAQ" ,"l" : "216.22" ,"l_fix" : "216.22" ,"l_cur" : "216.22" ,"s": "1" ,"ltt":"4:00PM EDT" ,"lt" : "May 23, 4:00PM EDT" ,"lt_dts" : "2016-05-23T16:00:01Z" ,"c" : "-4.06" ,"c_fix" : "-4.06" ,"cp" : "-1.84" ,"cp_fix" : "-1.84" ,"ccol" : "chr" ,"pcls_fix" : "220.28" ,"el": "217.50" ,"el_fix": "217.50" ,"el_cur": "217.50" ,"elt" : "May 24, 7:52AM EDT" ,"ec" : "+1.28" ,"ec_fix" : "1.28" ,"ecp" : "0.59" ,"ecp_fix" : "0.59" ,"eccol" : "chg" ,"div" : "" ,"yld" : "" } ]

Do you have any ideas how to get this?
Best wishes,
Vinc